indexing lists in python
I need to create a list in python to gather diverse information about a large number of people (name, date of birth, ID number, e-mail address, address, telephone number, ....).
I would like to store everything in a list where each person would have an index "i" starting from 0 and increasing. The goal would be to retrieve a specific information about person by simply using the index "i" and an abbreviation to indicate the type of info to retrieve about that person (name, id, tel, addr, email, ...).
How to define this and how to access specific elements for a given person?
I have done this previously in Fortran using derived data types where I use the following to retrieve various elements for a given person:
list(i)%name

list(i)%id

list(i)%tel

list(i)%addr

list(i)%email


I couldn't define the info type (name, id, email, addr, tel, ...) in the list to use it for indexing.

Use a list of dictionaries or objects.

If they're dictionaries, you write people_list[i]['name']. For objects it becomes people_list[i].name

class Person, with those attributes. Keep a list of instances of that class with that information.

You could use a list of dicts, that'd be the simplest:
people = [
  {"name": "John", "tel": "123"},
  {"name": "Lottie", "tel": "456"},
]

while True:
    q = input(f"Enter index (0..{len(people) - 1}) + field:")
    if not q:
        break
    idx_str, field = q.split(None, 1)
    try:
        idx = int(idx_str)
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid index (not a number)")
        continue
    try:
        person = people[idx]
    except IndexError:
        print("Invalid index (no such person)")
        continue
    print(person.get(field, "No such field"))

Enter index (0..1) + field:1 tel
456
Enter index (0..1) + field:1 name
Lottie
Enter index (0..1) + field:0 name
John
Enter index (0..1) + field:0 address
No such field
Enter index (0..1) + field:4 address
Invalid index (no such person)
Enter index (0..1) + field:foo foo
Invalid index (not a number)
Enter index (0..1) + field:


Here's a code that uses a class ContactBook() to create a contact book. You can add and modify the methods here but in general, the record() method lets you add a contact. You can call it how many ever times you want. Here I call it twice. Then, the save_in_rec() method basically appends the info to a defaultdict(). There are other ways you can do this but to answer your question and what you need, I think this is simple and can be adapted to your needs. Lastly, the get_info() method takes in the information type you are looking for and the number in the entry to get you the info you need. Hope this helps!
from collections import defaultdict

class ContactBook:
    def __init__(self):
        self.reg_number = None
        self.name = None
        self.address = None
        self.phone = None
        self.master = defaultdict(list)

    def record(self):
        self.name = input('Name: ')
        self.address = input('Address: ')
        self.phone = input('Phone: ')
        self.reg_number = input('Registration number: ')
        self.save_in_rec()

    def save_in_rec(self):
        self.master['reg_number'].append(self.reg_number)
        self.master['name'].append(self.name)
        self.master['address'].append(self.address)
        self.master['phone'].append(self.phone)

    def get_info(self, info_type, number):
        return self.master[info_type][number]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    contact = ContactBook()  # Create the address book
    contact.record()  # Record a contact
    contact.record()  # Record another contact
    print(contact.get_info('name', 0))  # Print the first name


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

If this helps answer your question, please consider accepting it or if you think it doesn't answer your question, please explain why! Thanks.

I tried to replicate this, but I struggle on how to get the index of an element that I added to the contact book. Say I have added contact info for 20 people, and later I need to gather all information about the contact person number 5.

Are you asking how to index a list? In the save_in_rec() method, things like 'reg_number', 'name' etc. are all lists. If you need all this info for index number 5 for example, you just index it. As in- contact.master['reg_number'][5] for the 'reg_number' and do the same for the others.
